# Curl wont connect to working proxy

Tags: php, curl

I updated php to 5.3.28 lately and for some reason curl isnt able to connect to proxies, and it times out. I set a little test to check it out and it runs ok on one server with php5.3.27 but not on this one.
testcode:

```
<?php

$proxy=$argv[1];

echo "Testing Proxy Status ...\n";
$testpage = "http://mydmain626.serveftp.com/rd/index.shtml";
$ch = curl_init($testpage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$code = $info;
echo $page;
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

run as:  `php curl_test.php 213.220.218.14:21320`

outputs this:

```
Testing Proxy Status ...
* About to connect() to proxy 213.220.218.14 port 21320 (#0)
*   Trying 213.220.218.14... * Timeout
* connect() timed out!
* Closing connection #0
```

when it should output this:

```
Testing Proxy Status ...
* About to connect() to proxy 213.220.218.14 port 21320 (#0)
*   Trying 213.220.218.14... * connected
* Connected to 213.220.218.14 (213.220.218.14) port 21320 (#0)
> GET http://mydmain626.serveftp.com/rd/index.shtml HTTP/1.1
Host: mydmain626.serveftp.com
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 23 Apr 2014 16:47:28 GMT
< Server: Apache/2
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
< Content-Length: 69
< Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Type: text/html
<
* Connection #0 to host 213.220.218.14 left intact
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<br>proxy_says_alive<br>
</body>
</html>* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Did you bother checking `curl_error($ch)` to see what (if any) message you're getting? As well, what is "not working"? PHP crashes? you get a 404? 500?

Comment: Sure i said its a timeout. Ill add the result above.

Comment: Php was compiled localy on the second server, i think thats where it all went wrong.

Comment: I doubt it's curl. timed out is more likely a firewall blocking the connection somewhere. either on your "bad curl" machine, or the proxy server has its service firewalled off to specific ips.

Comment: @MarcB Both machines are in the same network, so ips are not that different. I checked the firewall theory too, i tried to run that test with php5.2 before the update, and it was working fine.

Comment: similar ips doesn't mean anything if the firewall had a hole punched for only specific ips anyways. but since it's just an http proxy, you can always try the usual manual "telnet 213.220.218.14 21320" and see if THAT connects. If it doesn't, then it's NOT curl's problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51298/discussion-between-evan-and-marc-b)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the proxy and it's online, this should work for you:

```
$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '213.220.218.14:21320';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $curl_scraped_page;
```

Comment: Hey, thnx for your time but the error had to do with the iptables on the server.

Comment: @Evan I'm glad you found your solution :)